# Shell history support that doesn't suck?

Tags: macos, ubuntu, bash, shell, command-history

When I use multiple terminal sessions at once, bash only persists the commands from one of them.  Then later when I try to do a reverse command search, the command I want is not going to come up, because it didn't make it into the history.

I think this is terrible.  How can I get a shell history feature that can search back through all my commands, no matter what shell session they were in?  I'll gladly switch to a different shell than bash if that is required.

I'm using Mac OS X and Ubuntu.

Comment: I never managed to get a properly configured shared history with bash, even with complex hacks that save it at each command. I would suggest to switch to `ksh` (better the last one, ksh93) with which this is the default configuration.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest hack would be to add these lines in your .bashrc file:

```
shopt -s histappend
export PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -c; history -r; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

Variations around that technique are shown [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1288/preserve-bash-history-in-multiple-terminal-windows).

It might not be reliable in which case you might want to switch to `ksh` (better the last one, `ksh93`) with which this is the default configuration.